# Clob in oracle DB - variable size

Tags: sql, oracle

If I define a Clob data type on a table but don't specify the byte size, is the size variable or will it be saved with the maximum number of variables for that data type?

```
 CREATE TABLE "NOTIFICATIONS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "RECIPIENTS" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) DEFAULT 'both' NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "AGE_FROM" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "AGE_TO" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "MESSAGE_TITLE" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MESSAGE_BODY" CLOB, 
    "ATTACHMENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) DEFAULT 'none' NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "UPDATED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "DELETED_AT" TIMESTAMP (6), 
) ;
```

As you can see MESSAGE_BODY is of type clob but has no variable size. You may find that sometimes a string of 25,000 bytes is stored, other times 4,000 bytes, and perhaps 100,000 bytes.

Comment: You cannot specify the size of a CLOB column. Actual storage space is variable; most CLOB data winds up being stored "out of line" with the rest of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CLOB` data-type does not specify a size, Oracle will allocate as much space as is necessary for each individual `CLOB`.

If you do:

```sql
CREATE TABLE NOTIFICATIONS (
    MESSAGE_BODY CLOB(4000)
);
```

Then you get the exception:

> ```
> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
> ```

(Because an `(` is invalid syntax for the next token after defining the column's `CLOB` data type and, instead, valid syntax  would be a closing bracket to terminate the DDL statement and Oracle picks that as the likely expected syntax that should come next.)

But if you do:

```
CREATE TABLE NOTIFICATIONS (
    MESSAGE_BODY CLOB
);
```

Then it works.
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/14InLG2G)

Answer (score 5):

You can't specify a size for a `clob`.  Oracle will only use as much space as it needs.  Since a single `clob` has a maximum size of several TB (exactly how many depends on the Oracle version and the block size of your tablespace), it would be pretty catastrophic if Oracle were to allocate multiple TB of space for every row you inserted.

Just as an aside, that's the same behavior you see with `varchar2` columns.  Declaring a column as `varchar2(255 byte)` declares that the value in the column can't exceed 255 bytes but Oracle will only allocate as much space as necessary to store the data if it is less than 255 bytes.  `char` is the only data type that would space pad the inserted data to the maximum size of the column.  And that's one of the reason that you basically never declare a column as `char`.